# Testing an Android device resolution using Robotium

Tags: android, device, junit4, resolution, robotium

Is there a way we can test an android device's resolution?

Comment: What do you mean by "testing" the resolution? I mean you can always use any of the standard ways to retrieve that info.

Comment: For example, I want to test if the resolution is 400*400.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In any test function you can write following code:

```
    Activity ACT = getActivity();


    Display display = ACT.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;
    int height = size.y;
```

or if API<13

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth(); 
int height = display.getHeight();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this Help : [If u r planning to run same test code for Phone/Tablet]

```
Configuration mConfig = mContext.getResources().getConfiguration();

// checking for XLarge screen ...U can also check for Large screen similarly    
if ((mConfig.screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE) {  

        Log.i("TABLET MODE");
        // Do ur actions for Tablet
}
```